# RecyclerView.Adapter is null in ViewPager Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-pageradapter

```
public class MainLibraryFragment extends Fragment implements PlaylistChangedInterface {

AudioItemSelectedListener mCallback;

// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface AudioItemSelectedListener {
    //        public void onAudioItemSelected(int position);
    public void onAudioItemSelected(Audio audioSelected);
}

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private Context context;

private ArrayList<Audio> listToDisplay;

private String TAG = "MainLibraryFragment";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    context = getActivity();

    MemoryManagement memoryManagement = new MemoryManagement(context);
    listToDisplay = memoryManagement.loadAudioList(MemoryManagement.MAIN_LIST_KEY);
    try {
        //Expression is meaningless but tests if null.
        //TODO, should catch this in loadAudioList.
        if (listToDisplay.isEmpty()){}
    } catch (NullPointerException e){
        defaultList();
    }

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), LinearLayoutCompat.VERTICAL));
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new CustomTouchListener(context, new onItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int index) {

            mCallback.onAudioItemSelected(listToDisplay.get(index));

        }
    }));

    mAdapter = new SongListAdapter2(listToDisplay, context);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

private void defaultList(){
    listToDisplay = new ArrayList<>();
    listToDisplay.add(new Audio("You need to add some songs!"));
}

@Override
public void playListChanged(ArrayList<Audio> arrayList) {
    Log.d(TAG, "updateTop: in.");
    if (!arrayList.isEmpty()) {
        listToDisplay = arrayList;
    }else {
        defaultList();
    }

    updateListView();
    Log.d(TAG, "updateTop: out.");
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context = getContext();
    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (AudioItemSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement AudioItemSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallback = null;
}

private void updateListView(){
    Log.d(TAG, "updateTop: in.");

    ((SongListAdapter2) mAdapter).refreshList(listToDisplay);
    Log.d(TAG, "updateTop: out.");
}
}
```

I have added refreshList():

```
    public void refreshList(ArrayList<Audio> list) {
    this.list = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And then the error message:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
06-09 15:14:24.275 9114-9114/com.bteq.audia E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bteq.audia, PID: 9114
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.bteq.audia.SongListAdapter2.refreshList(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference
    at com.bteq.audia.MainLibraryFragment.updateListView(MainLibraryFragment.java:128)
    at com.bteq.audia.MainLibraryFragment.playListChanged(MainLibraryFragment.java:100)
    at com.bteq.audia.MainActivity.onDialogPositiveClick(MainActivity.java:195)
    at com.bteq.audia.AddSongDialog$2.onClick(AddSongDialog.java:47)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
06-09 15:14:24.281 9114-9114/com.bteq.audia W/OPDiagnose: 
getService:OPDiagnoseService NULL
```

The MainActivity that contains the Pager. I tried to remove as much code as I could that wasn't relevant.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainLibraryFragment.AudioItemSelectedListener, AddSongDialog.NoticeDialogListener, ShowQueueDialog.ShouldClearAll {

private MemoryManagement memoryManagement;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private com.bteq.audia.PagerAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    memoryManagement = new MemoryManagement(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    initialiseViews();
}

public void initialiseViews() {

    //Fills the titles of all the tabs.
    String[] tabTitles = getTabTitles();
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabTitles.length; i++) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(tabTitles[i]));
    }
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    //Sets up the ViewPager and creates the functionality to make them changeable.
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    setupBottomView();
}

//method used as main control to the service from this activity.
private void audioActionDo(String audioAction) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("audio_control_intent");
    intent.putExtra("button_pressed", audioAction);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}

/*
Method tells the activity which item in the shown playlist has been selected. This should then cause that item to play if possible.
//TODO, fill in body of method.
 */
@Override
public void onAudioItemSelected(Audio audio) {
    songSelected(audio);

    Log.d("MainActivity", "onAudioItemSelected: At end");
}

@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(String titleString, String artistString, String albumString, String genreString) {
    Audio audioToAdd = new Audio(genreString, titleString, albumString, artistString);

    memoryManagement.addAudioToList(audioToAdd, MemoryManagement.MAIN_LIST_KEY);

    Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(0);
    PlaylistChangedInterface playlistChangedInterface = (PlaylistChangedInterface) fragment;
    playlistChangedInterface.playListChanged(memoryManagement.loadAudioList(MemoryManagement.MAIN_LIST_KEY));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_top, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            //TODO, take the user to the app settings page.
            // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
            return true;

        case R.id.action_favorite:
            //TODO, make this favourite the current Audio.
            // User chose the "Favorite" action, mark the current item
            // as a favorite...
            memoryManagement.clearPrefsValue(MemoryManagement.MAIN_LIST_KEY);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_add_new_song:
            showAddSongDialog();
            return true;

        case R.id.action_show_queue:
            showQueueDialog();
            return true;

        case R.id.action_add_from_internal:

            return true;

        default:
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}

public void showAddSongDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new AddSongDialog();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "missiles");
}

public void showQueueDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new ShowQueueDialog();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "showQueue");
}

//Should immediately play a song then be able to continue with the queued audio.
public void songSelected(Audio audioToAdd) {

}

//clears the entire queue but completes playback of current audio.
private void clearCurrentQueue() {
    memoryManagement.clearPrefsValue(MemoryManagement.QUEUE_KEY);
}

//   Utility method. Returns the locale titles for the tabs in the viewpager.
private String[] getTabTitles() {
    return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_titles);
}

@Override
public void clearAllPressed() {
    clearCurrentQueue();
}

private void setupBottomView() {
    ImageView playButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_play);
    ImageView replayButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_replay);
    ImageView skipBackButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_skip_back);
    ImageView skipForwardButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_skip_next);
    ImageView shuffleButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_shuffle);

    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//                playAudio(storageUtility2.loadAudioIndex());

audioActionDo(getResources().getString(R.string.broadcast_action_playpause));
        }
    });
    replayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            audioActionDo(getResources().getString(R.string.broadcast_action_loop));
        }
    });
    skipBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            audioActionDo(getResources().getString(R.string.broadcast_action_skip_back));
        }
    });
    skipForwardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            audioActionDo(getResources().getString(R.string.broadcast_action_skip_forward));
        }
    });
    shuffleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            audioActionDo(getResources().getString(R.string.broadcast_action_shuffle));
        }
    });
}
```

}

I get a **null pointer exception** whenever the method updateListView is called. The fragment initially displays with no problem, but when a new entry is added to the ArrayList and the updateListView is called - it stops. The log shows that mAdapter is null. I don't know enough about android yet to understand why mAdapter becomes null after it is used before.

Sorry for large amount of code but I'm completely stumped. Thanks.

Comment: Post the error logcat and also content of `refreshList()` method, please.

Comment: @jantursky have done

Comment: Looks like the main problem will be in logic of handling fragment inside Activity. Check it or post that code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is because your variable `mAdapter` is declared as of type `RecyclerView.Adapter` which is an interface which does not declare your method, `refreshList()`. Therefore if you intend to use the type RecyclerView.Adapter, only the methods declared in the interface could be called by using the reference variable. If you intend to call methods implemented by yourself other than whats overridden from the interface, the reference type `SongListAdapter2` has to be used.

Simple fix is to change the `RecyclerView.Adapter` to `SongListAdapter2` at the declaration of the `mAdapter`.

Ps. Check android [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter) to see the methods declared by the RecyclerView.Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are accessing the adapter in the RecyclerView. If you look at this line `Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(0)`, you are trying to access the first fragment in your ViewPager's adapter. getItem usually won't get called again after the ViewPager has layout its fragments which means your call to access the RecyclerView's adapter in the first fragment in the ViewPager will be pointing to a null adapter even though the fragment might exist (and you might even be calling a wrong fragment). Use this `Fragment fragment = getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0)` to access the right fragment which will ensure the RecyclerView adapter won't be null. Change getChildFragmentManager() to getFragmentManager() if your ViewPager is in an Activity.